# render() function to return default <slot /> in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

A real simple question. I'm wondering, I have the following template:

```
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

within a `ProviderComponent.vue`.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use a render function to replace the use of `<template>` and `<slot>` in this case in Vue 3?

I can't seem to find anything in the docs or else where ... but I'm sure it is more than possible.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#rendering-slots

Answer (score 0):

Slots are available in setup context.

It is:

```
setup(props, ctx) {
  return () => ctx.slots.default?.() ?? null;
}
```